# Do WebSockets have exclusive access to their sockets?

Tags: http, sockets, websocket

I'm curious to know if, after a WebSocket has been established (after having received the proper handshake from a server that supports them), whether or not the TCP socket used by the "WebSocket connection" is used exclusively by the WebSocket, or if the browser may still make regular HTTP requests with it.

It only makes sense to me that WebSockets would have exclusive use of their TCP sockets, but I don't remember having read in any of the documentation that such is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, yes they do.  WebSockets end up operating rather like ordinary sockets.

Joe Armstrong says so: http://armstrongonsoftware.blogspot.com/